# Shouldn't instantaneous velocity be the limit as both the displacement and time approach zero?

Tags: velocity, differentiation, calculus

This is how Feynman defines velocity:

\begin{equation*}
v=\lim_{\Delta t\to0}\frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t}=d{s}/d{t}.
\end{equation*}

However, as the time interval gets smaller, the corresponding displacement should also get smaller, and therefore would it not be more correct to write it as:

\begin{equation*}
v=\lim_{\Delta (t,s)\to(0,0)}\frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t}=d{s}/d{t}.
\end{equation*}

Comment: Note that $\Delta s$ depends on $\Delta t$, and therefore $\Delta t\to 0$ already forces $\Delta s\to 0$. No need to take $\Delta s\to 0$ separately.

Comment: Why would that be more correct?

Answer (score 2):

One should take into account that a multivariable limit, as defined, applies only to independent variables. The function is NOT V(s,t), because s=s(t). V is a single-variable function, V(t). And the limit of a single-variable function can never be a multivariable limit.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's assumed here that $\Delta s$ is a continuous function of $\Delta t$, so that when $\Delta t$ goes to zero, so should $\Delta s$.

In any case, the only way for $ds/dt$ to exist in a continuous sense is if we have a function $s(t)$ to differentiate.